# What's the diff between Cache and Application?

Tags: asp.net

I just noticed a "Cache" object, when would you use the Cache object to store state data nd when would you use the Application object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything that you put in the Application state collection stays there.

When you put something in the Cache collection you can specify how long it will stay there and how important it is in relation to other objects in the cache. You can store any amount of data in the cahce, and the system will decide what to throw away depending on the current memory usage.